# NPE when switching tabs on SwipeRefreshLayout @ v23.2.0

Tags: android, android-support-library

After updating the support lib to version 23.2.0

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
```

I started getting this error when switching between tabs (Android version 5.0.2):

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setAlpha(int)' on a null object reference
   at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.setColorViewAlpha(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:217)
   at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.reset(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:199)
   at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onDetachedFromWindow(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:213)
   at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:14579)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:3138)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:3135)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:3135)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:4502)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:4475)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.removeView(ViewGroup.java:4407)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.removeView(ViewPager.java:1430)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1165)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeFragment(FragmentManager.java:1349)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:708)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:164)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:608)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:570)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:551)
   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1991)
   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1024)
   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:994)
   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1262)
   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:1360)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20978)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6134)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Seems like a support library bug, is anybody out there also having this issue? Any workaround?

Comment: I am also facing same problem. Have you found any solution ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: in my case setBackgroundDrawable(null); was causing the problem

Comment: Checkout: [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35713793/npe-when-switching-tabs-on-swiperefreshlayout-v23-2-0/44678694#44678694)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the all the library's there might be overriding some resources 'void android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setAlpha(int)'.  The void setAlpha(null)

Comment: Good call! Not quite the actual problem but it threw me off in the right direction. I was using a utility method that was setting the ImageView drawables and background drawables to null hoping to release memory a bit quicker

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this problem, but if it is indeed in the SwipeRefreshLayout widget, you could subclass it and wrap the onDetachedFromWindow call with a try/catch block.

```
public class MySwipeRefreshLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout {
    // constructor methods here

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        try {
            super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        catch (Exception ignore) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exception thrown into following part of code:

```
private void setColorViewAlpha(int targetAlpha) {
    mCircleView.getBackground().setAlpha(targetAlpha);
    mProgress.setAlpha(targetAlpha);
}
```

Here the mCircleView **(CircleImageView)** is an instance of ImageView. If you are performing any action for release memory at any point in your app something like that:

```
public void unbindDrawables(View view) {
    try {
        if (view != null) {

            if (view.getBackground() != null) {
                view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
            }
            if (view instanceof ImageView) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
                if (imageView != null) {
                    Drawable drawable = ((ImageView) view).getDrawable();
                    if (drawable != null && drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                        drawable.setCallback(null);
                    }
                    imageView.setBackgroundResource(0);
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
                     imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
                }
            } else if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                    unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
                }

                if ((view != null) && !(view instanceof AdapterView)) {
                    ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
                }
            }

            view = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //TODO:: handle Exception
    }
}
```

In the above code

```
if (view instanceof ImageView) {
                        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
                        if (imageView != null) {
                            Drawable drawable = ((ImageView) view).getDrawable();
                            if (drawable != null && drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                                drawable.setCallback(null);
                            }
                            imageView.setBackgroundResource(0);
                            imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
                             imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
                        }
                    }
```

these part makes mCircleView and it's Drawable both **NULL**, and when **SwipeRefreshLayout** called for reset then that exception thrown.